# Visual Studio Hosting Process locks my files

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, msbuild, vshost.exe

On every build, I copy a few managed and unmanaged libraries to my $(TargetDir)libs\ folder. However, since I'm referencing one of the managed dlls in Visual Studio, somehow the **Visual Studio Hosting Process** (*vshost.exe*) locks the file, resulting in a exit code 1 from copy.

What can I do about this?

Answer (score 0):

You can disable the hosting process from project properties. It's in the Debug tab, as below:

[image]